# React js application's css styling be overriden when opened in hosted application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a React js application that is hosted in another application. The React application is launched when a jquery dialog is opened. The React application works as expected, but some of its CSS is out of place, and thus can only suspect that either the hosted application's CSS is overriding it or jquery is doing something to affect it.

There I would ask whether there is away to prevent this. I have tried using !important syntax against the Reactjs css (we are using scss in React), but this has had no effect.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Currently working on micro app, which will be included in existing web page. To prevent these bugs, I use CSS modules which generate unique class names. More info about CSS modules concept here https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules. To solve your issue: assuming you cannot change hosting application/website, adjust class names in your (hosted) react app.

Comment: I recommend looking into using inline-styles for your reactjs app. There are modular approaches that will allow you to style your react app using inline-styles.

Comment: Solved the problem with Facebook inline styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with Facebook inline styling

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559294/shield-react-component-from-outside-styles/37039531#37039531). Wrapping your component in an iframe will help. Check out the project's [github](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component). Good luck!